# how to send information to a define with a tkinter button

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to create a menu for a school project and wanted to make it so that it reads the files in a given directory and creates buttons on the screen based on what files are there. My main problem at the moment is that I can't get the Button to send the information i need.

I've tried to use the functions in a different way but this is the closest I can get to what I want.

```
class Menu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        #working out how big to make the window
        global files_in_area
        files_in_area = []
        files_in_area = os.listdir(menu_folder_loc)
        print files_in_area
        a = len(files_in_area)
        b = 3
        rows = a / b
        rows = rows + 1
        window_height = rows * 56
        root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (450, window_height, 0, 0))
        Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master
        self.init_menu()
    def init_menu(self):
        self.master.title("Menu")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        for i in range(0, len(files_in_area)):
            #button placment
            a = i
            b = 3
            row_no = a / b
            row_no = row_no + 1
            column_no = a % b
            global file_name
            file_name = str(files_in_area[i])
            b1 = Button(self, text=file_name, bg= "red", height=3, width=20, command=self.client_print_file).grid(row=row_no, column=column_no, sticky=W)
    def client_print_file(self):
        print file_name
```

I've got the code to work when finding the files and putting them in a tkinter window, and when I click on the button, it should open the file (I'm just printing the file name at the moment to make sure it works). However it just prints the last file in the list.

Sorry if this question is a bit confusing, and thanks in advance.

Comment: *"prints the last file in the list."*: It prints nothing from `files_in_area`, you are printing the value of the `global file_name`.

Comment: I've tried to use a value for the button so I can get it to read from the main array itself, but I can't get that to work, it always says that an incorrect number of arguments are given. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: *"Is there any way to get around that?"*: Yes, search for [`[python] [tkinter] [button]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+tkinter+button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem about tkinter but about scopes and oop in python. I assume you got started with python by reading online stuff or got a fast introduction. My first advice is: do not use/copy from someone else's code something if you do not understand it. If you copy, try to dig in yourself and MAKE it your own code. One good way of reading up stuff is the very good online documentation of python.
Some exercises to get you started: 1) Research about python's scoping of variables.
2) More importantly: read up on classes, i.e. object oriented programming.

To the code: 1) Ditch the use of `global` alltogether. No need here. If you want to use the variable `files_in_area` in all methods of the class simply make it an attribute of the class, just like you did with `master` which you then go on to use in another method where it was not defined! Now to the variable `filename`: Again, ditch global. Then filename lives in the scope of the for loop which is exactly what you want here.

See it like this: if you had not used the variable filename at all but simply put `text=str(files_in_area[i])` inside the Button-constructor as argument, you wouldnt have run into this problem here - at its core this really is a problem about thinking for yourself and not copying too much code from someone else - I know it because this was a big issue for me for long time.

The hardest thing here is how to pass a command depending on the `i` of the for loop to each button. You can find a lot here on stackoverflow. This again is about variables and their scope but also about their binding. In each loop pass, we want to generate a value of command depending on `i`. One way to use this is using the (at first mystical) `lambda`: `command=lambda i=i: self.client_print_file(i)`. And define `def client_print_file(self, i):` ... with an additional argument `i`. The critical thing here is the binding. What would not work is `command=lambda i: self.client_print_file(i)`. 
(Another way instead of using lambda would be using partial from functools...)
Assignment: read up on lambda and what it is about and about name binding and variables in python :)

Comment: Thank you. I've been stuck on this for ages and it worked first time. I had coded a menu before but didn't make the buttons from files. I think I've confused myself with my understanding of classes.